# Intergrating WordPress Plugins into a bootstrap site

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4

I hope you do not mind if I ask a general questions regarding bootstrap and WordPress.

I have created a website using just bootstrap. I am trying to set up an Appointment Booking System on it. I know that in WordPress there is a good plugin for this that would work well.

I have two questions regarding the above statement.

1. Is there a way that I can keep my customized bootstrap theme and integrate a WordPress plug in into my site without having to build the site from scratch in WordPress.

2) Is there a way to load my bootstrap code into the WordPress portal (so it is a customized bootstrap site) but that I would be able to use all of the available WordPress plugins.

Thanks

Colm.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly, if you want to use your custom html you need to create a custom WordPress theme. By the way, this is not difficult at all, and if you have already your static files setted up, splitting them in a theme is almost straigth forward.

Before stepping into it and start trying some good starter blank themes (underscores, timber, root etc..) my advice is: follow a simple guide and learn core WordPress theme hierarchy, then you'll be able to do almost anything.

This is the first guid I found but - ehi - Google is your best friend!

https://scanwp.net/blog/create-a-wordpress-starter-theme-from-scratch/